# Bisonc++ - Verbose reporting to return conflicting rules?

Tags: bisonc++

I have a massive problem with bisonc++'s compiler: The error messages are garbage. It's really hard for me to find the problem, when all it says is `Line 63: 2 Reduce/Reduce conflict(s)` (line 63 is the last line of the code). Is there a way, a switch or anything to make bisonc++ also return the rules that cause the conflict? Any verbose error reporting? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [bisonc++ man pages](https://fbb-git.github.io/bisoncpp/bisonc++man.html), you can request a detailed output that gets written into a .output file with the -V switch.

> - **--verbose (-V)**
>
> Writes a file containing verbose descriptions of the parser states and what is done for each type of look-ahead token in
> that state. This file also describes all conflicts detected in the
> grammar, both those resolved by operator precedence and those that
> remain unresolved. It is not created by default, but if requested the
> information is written on .output, where  is the
> grammar specification file passed to bisonc++